# Radish Test Framework

Tags: python-2.7, bdd, feature-file

I am new to the Radish Test Framework and got confused by the way of executing the test using feature files. Please clarify on:
I have installed radish module(pip install radish-bdd) already. Is there any other step to follow?
In the example, it shows to execute like "radish calculator.feature" (sample eg)
How radish behaves as the command, instead i have got it as a directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/radish" after pip install.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is. If I understand you, you're having trouble executing tests. With radish installed you'll want to run `radish <path_to_feature_file>` So for example, lets say that we have a feature file called `test.feature` which is located in the same directory as we are, we have a few options...

Run only that feature file

```
radish test.feature
```

Run every feature file in the current directory

```
radish .
```

Comment: Along with radish-bdd, i installed radish(pip install radish) and radish-run(pip install radish-run).. Then it worked for me!! Thanks for the response.. :)